# What's the difference between SideEffect and Condition? how to figure out?

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction, language-features, aspect

I'm working on aspect extraction in drug review.

There are 7 kind of aspects, but I can't find any role to find the difference between two of them .

```
'''
Condition :
" I have extreme anxiety disorder "
" some fatigue symptoms "
'''
```

...

```
Side Effect :
"I get drowsiness during the day "
" I couch feeling like dizzy "
" day dream some times"
```

Now I can't find out any role to figure out and extract differences between these two type of aspect .

Comment: hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. This is not really a programming question. But in general, a *condition* is what the patient has before taking the drug (hyperlipidemia, PTSD, gout). A *side effect* is what happens to the patient as a result of taking the drug (e.g., this drug may cause drowsiness).

Comment: thanks, but how can i find it with an algorythm ?

Comment: That's really up to you as a programmer, and depends on your skill and which tools are at your disposal. If you have a lot of data (say 500 sentences) that is already labeled as "condition" or "side effect", you can use a Machine Learning technique such as logistic regression to classify. There is a solid toolkit called Scikit Learn that can help you implement this.